# How to plot a pixel onto Bitmap in F# or C# rather than an anti-aliased point?

Tags: c#, plot, f#, pixel, system.drawing

I use System.Drawing and System.Windows.Forms a lot for plotting pixels to a bitmap, but I've noticed it's never actually a single pixe. It's more like a 3x3 dot with the edges blurred. How can I plot just a pixel? Currently I'm using `bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, color)`.

F#

```
open System.Drawing

let bitmap = new Bitmap(256, 256)

for x in 0 .. 255 do
    for y in 0 .. 255 do
        bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White)
```

Comment: When you draw a area, it is not a good idea to use `SetPixel` method. Use `graphics.FillRectangle(brush, bounds)` _(this is a small example from my code of a custom/tweaked control)_. `SetPixel` is very, very slow _(for more pixels)_.

Comment: I know, I just used that as an example. Otherwise the post would have been really short.

Comment: I never had a blur on controls using this method. Are your sure, that the blur is not from a different source _(e.g. picture viewer; I saw picture viewers that stretched pictures and added blur for 'better/more natural feeling' on photos)_.

Comment: Hm, it could be. I am using the default Windows image viewer and saving the image with .Save(). I'll try it with a different viewer now.

Comment: @Julo I had to edit it with Paint 3D after 3 other programs to finally see that it is indeed just a pixel. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When displaying the Bitmap, you can turn anti-aliasing off.

```
graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half;
```

Bitmap.SetPixel does just change one pixel, it doesn't cause any anti-aliasing effect.